# Horizontal Layout Inside a Vertical Layout or GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am new to android programming and was wondering if someone could help with providing any info or link or code to help me create the image below.

[Final OutCome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqkrc.png)

Comment: AFAIK `RecyclerView` `LinearlayoutManager` and a StickyHeader. If you have unlimited rows .

Comment: use Table layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="line e" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="line e" />

      </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to help you . Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

use table layout here is a sample example

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableHead"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="S.No"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="2" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Count"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="3" />
    </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">

            <TextView
                android:text="S.No"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="2" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Count"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="3" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:text="S.No"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="2" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Count"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="3" />
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```